# Android Room + RxJava - How to do multiple inserts from tests

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I have an in-memory Room database for testing.

I want to call insert multiple times.

My DAO looks like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun addUser(user: User)

@Query("SELECT name FROM users")
fun getUsers(): Flowable<List<String>>
```

My DAOTest looks like this.

```
val user1 = User(id = 1, name = "Andy")
userDao.adduser(user1).blockingAwait()
val user2 = User(id = 2, name = "Ben")
userDao.adduser(user2).blockingAwait()
val resultList = listOf(user1.name, user2.name) 
val testObserver = userDao.getUserNames().test()
testObserver.assertResult(resultList)
```

The getUserNames() has only the value list("Ben"). How do I ensure that the 1st addUser() call is successful and then add the second user?

Comment: Are you sure that "Ben" is not replacing "Andy"? What happens if you remove `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`?

Comment: Yes, that was it.